Disabling Ubuntu Ctrl+Alt+delete still reboots the system if key command is given multiple times within a short time
I have disabled ctrl+alt+DEL key command using sudo systemctl mask ctrl-alt-del.target and sudo systemctl daemon-reload.
But even after this, the system reboots if I give the ctrl+alt+DEL key command continuously.
Is this a know issue with Ubuntu or if this is the expected behavior?
PS: I'm using only the cli interface via SSH. So answers based on GUI don't help.

It is expected behavior.
From the manual systemd-system.conf(5)
CtrlAltDelBurstAction=
    Defines what action will be performed if user presses Ctrl-Alt-Delete
    more than 7 times in 2s. Can be set to "reboot-force", "poweroff-force",
    "reboot-immediate", "poweroff-immediate" or disabled with "none". Defaults
    to "reboot-force".

